# How do I store the user uid to firebase database after I register an account?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Here's my code in .js

```
$("#loginBtn").click(
function(){


var email = $("#loginEmail").val();
var password = $("#loginPassword").val();

if(email != "" && password != ""){
  $("#loginProgress").show();
  $("#loginBtn").hide();
  $("#registerBtn").hide();

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    $("#loginError").show().text(errorMessage);
    $("#loginProgress").hide();
    $("#loginBtn").show();
    $("#register_account_Btn").hide();
    $("#back_btn").hide();

  });
 }
}
);

/* REGISTER PROCESS */

$("#register_account_Btn").click(
 function () {
var email = $("#regEmail").val();
var password = $("#regPassword").val();

if(email != "" && password != ""){
  $("#loginProgress").show();
  $("#loginBtn").hide();

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,
   password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    $("#loginError").show().text(errorMessage);
    $("#loginProgress").hide();
    $("#loginBtn").show();
    $("#register_account_Btn").hide();
    $("#back_btn").hide();

  });
}
```

I found this on the internet but I don't know where to insert it.
Is this correct?

```
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  firebase.database().ref().child('accounts').child(uid).set({
    email: user.email,
    userId: uid
  })
```

Should I create another function?

and these are the rules in my firebase database. Is it advisable to use this?
Additional Question:
I want to create a user roles: teacher and student. Teacher can create classroom, add students, view the list of students. While the student can view his/her classmates and teacher. How should I do this?

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
      }
    }
   }
```

Sincerest apology but I'm new to this ;(

Answer (score 4):

The `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function returns a `Promise: firebase.User`.

You're only catching exceptions with your code, if you chain a `.then` onto the function you can get the user information and save that user to the data.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(user => {
    // Save user here.
    return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.uid).set({
      email: user.email,
      uid: user.uid
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
  });
```

Your other question around the teacher / student is very broad - try to narrow it down to a solution and if you get stuck with some specific create a new question.

Comment: It's not working sir :( can I send you my source code so that you can determine the error?

Comment: when I add the .then(user => .....etc) in the firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password), my register.html (inputs) won't appear

Comment: The line below the `// Save user here.` comment.

Comment: Ahh I see, the .show() you mean is like this one $("#loginProgress").show();

Comment: Yup - exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 5.0.0 of the [Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_500_-_may_8_2018), `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` returns a Promise containing the new user's credentials as a [`UserCredentials`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html?#user-credential) object instead of a [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html) object.

However, the `UserCredentials` object contains the `User` object as it's `user` property, which you can get the new email and user ID from as in [@sketchthat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52158558/3068190).

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(credential => {
    // Save user here.
    return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + credential.user.uid).set({
      email: credential.user.email,
      uid: credential.user.uid
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
  });
```